# Is there a "warning" element in jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to display a warning in jQuery mobile, but cannot find a style/element designed for this purpose. The only thing I found was an alert icon, at least.

It should look something like this yellow note:
[image]

---

**Is there such a thing or do I have to create it myself?**

Comment: Do you want this as a dialog or something? Otherwise, I can’t see how this is jQuery Mobile specific … what you have shown, is just simple text content on a yellow-ish background – simple formatting via CSS is all that would need.

Comment: No, it should just show up as an important note. A dialog is not necessary.

Comment: Well then give it a class to classify it as a notice, and format it as desired via CSS …

Comment: jQM doesn't offer a warning element, create your own.

Comment: @Omar Can you write this as official answer, then I can close this topic and mark your response as answer

Comment: I can't write such an answer, you can simply leave the topic open, or just delete it if you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no standard element/style or any other way anymore to do so since version 1.4.3.